# Modeling a ball gear

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model a ball gear (not a worm gear) in blender, like the one in [this](https://www.cnc4you.co.uk/image/cache/catalog/Ballscrew%20and%20Ballnut-500x500.JPG) picture.

[image]

I have tried using the worm gear from the extra objects add on, but I can't get it to look right. Can anyone give me some tips?

Here is what I have been able to make so far: [image: The teeth don't look right]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Consider a Curve Modifier and Array.
Similar to winding cable around a spindle.**

---

[image]

- Curve Above.

[image]

- Mesh Component Selected.  Modifiers Array and Curve.

Comment: Looks good I'll try tomorrow. Don't mind me saying, but... Your theme looks totally horrific 