# Spinning existing vertices around a point

Tags: mesh

I wanted to know if it's possible to rotate a part of a mesh around a point? A bit like what the spinning tool is doing but for the selected vertices of an existing mesh.

For example on the image below, how could I spin this selected vertices around the 3D cursor in order to have a nice curve like on the object on the left?

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: Yuu can use the warp tool, the selected faces will curve using the 3d cursor as the radius (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21707/1853). For other forms of deformation read this related post: [how to curve my mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34598/how-to-curve-my-mesh)

Comment: I reccommend the 'simple deform' modifier set to 'bend' using an empty as origin of rotation.

Comment: Consider a curve modifier. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91902/modeling-a-ball-gear/91917#91917

Comment: ¿Are you stating you want this mechanism to generate vertices or NOT to generate vertices?  Spin tool generates.  Some others do not. ❓

Comment: Yes, non generative - thanks to everybody I could solve it with the SimpleDeform modifier as suggested by some people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these illustrations, the track to be deformed is lying in the XY plane, Y up, X across.

You can use the spin tool to generate new geometry: *extend* your object around an arc of a circle, by selecting the top row of existing vertices, and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> spinning them. In the Tool region, set the Axis to (0,0,1), the Angle to 90 degrees, and the Center to the center of the circle from which the arc is taken. (The empty in this illustration is just to show roughly where the center is)

[image]

But it's hard to adjust the center without constructing guidelines, and destructive. It's probably easier to use Simple Deform > Bend, with these settings, and an empty oriented and placed as shown:

[image]

That example uses the 'Limit' setting to restrict the deformation to the halfway point in the track's X, in the empty's space. You may need to slide that up and down, depending on the extent of your track in the empty's X.

Or...

[image]

.. you can restrict the deformation to a vertex group. (The angle setting becomes a bit counter-intuitive)

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know this SimpleDeform modifier yet, I learned a new valuable things in Blender today :)

Answer (score -1):

[image]

The spin tool affects only the current selection.